# How to user bloc for logging in?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, bloc

I am using a login bloc in my app. I just updated my packages and now it is not working. Before it would go to the sign-in screen or the homepage depending on if the user was logged in already. Now it is stuck in the loading screen. This is what I have,

```
LoginBloc({
    @required this.signInWithFacebook,
    @required this.signInWithGoogle,
    @required this.signOutWithGoogle,
    @required this.getLoggedInUserData,
    @required this.signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    @required this.signUpWithEmailAndPassword,
    @required this.updateAccountInfo,
    @required this.deleteAccountData,
    }) : super(InitialState());

    //@override
    //LoginState get initialState => InitialState();

    @override
    Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(
    LoginEvent event,
    ) async* {
    if (event is SignInWithGoogleEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();

      yield* _signInOrSignUpEitherHandler(() => signInWithGoogle(NoParam()));
    } else if (event is SignOutWithGoogleEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();

      final signOutGoogleEither = await signOutWithGoogle(NoParam());

      yield signOutGoogleEither.fold(
        (failure) => ErrorState(message: failure.message),
        (_) => LoggedOutState(),
      );
    } else if (event is SignInWithFacebookEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();

      yield* _signInOrSignUpEitherHandler(() => signInWithFacebook(NoParam()));
    } else if (event is CheckLoggedInStateEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();

      final loggedInStateEither = await getLoggedInUserData(NoParam());

      yield loggedInStateEither.fold(
        (failure) => AlertMessageState(message: failure.message),
        (userData) => LoggedInState(user: userData),
      );
    } else if (event is SignInWithEmailAndPasswordEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();

      yield* _signInOrSignUpEitherHandler(
        () => signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          LoginParams(email: event.email, password: event.password),
        ),
      );
    } else if (event is SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();

      loggedUpUsingEmail = true;

      yield* _signInOrSignUpEitherHandler(
        () => signUpWithEmailAndPassword(event.user),
      );
      // if ((await last) is LoggedInState) {
      //   yield SignedUpWithEmailState();
      // }
    } else if (event is UpdateAccountInfoEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();
      final updateAccountEither = await updateAccountInfo(event.user);

      yield updateAccountEither.fold(
        (failure) => ErrorState(message: failure.message),
        (successMessage) => AlertMessageState(message: successMessage),
      );
    } else if (event is DeleteAccountInfoEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();

      final deleteAccountEither = await deleteAccountData(event.user);

      yield* deleteAccountEither.fold(
        (failure) async* {
          yield ErrorState(message: failure.message);
        },
        (successMessage) async* {
          yield LoggedOutState();
          yield AlertMessageState(message: successMessage);
          yield AccountDeletedState();
        },
      );
    }
  

    bool loggedUpUsingEmail = false;
    Stream<LoginState> _signInOrSignUpEitherHandler(usecase) async* {
    final signInOrSignUpEither = await usecase();

    yield* signInOrSignUpEither.fold(
      (failure) async* {
        yield ErrorState(message: failure.message);
      },
      (userData) async* {
        if (loggedUpUsingEmail) {
          yield SignedUpWithEmailState();
          loggedUpUsingEmail = false;
        }
        yield LoggedInState(user: userData);
      },
    );
```

This is the part of my main where I make calls to this

```
return MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider(
      create: (_) {
        final bloc = serviceLocator<LoginBloc>();
        bloc.add(CheckLoggedInStateEvent());
        return bloc;
      },
    ),
```

Now when I run it, this part

```
  else if (event is CheckLoggedInStateEvent) {
  yield LoadingState();

  final loggedInStateEither = await getLoggedInUserData(NoParam());

  yield loggedInStateEither.fold(
    (failure) => AlertMessageState(message: failure.message),
    (userData) => LoggedInState(user: userData),
  );
```

returns this error:

[image: error].

I have been looking through some docs but can't find what I am doing wrong.